# How to get primary key inside detailview and use to pre fill a hidden field in a form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I have two models: Properties and Bedroom, which are connected through a foreign key "Property" on the Bedroom model.

```
 #models.py  

class Property(models.Model):
        property_reference = models.CharField(db_column='Property_Reference', max_length=10, unique=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        address = models.CharField(db_column='Address', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        post_code = models.CharField(db_column='Post_Code', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, choices=HOUSE_TYPE_CHOICES)  # Field name made lowercase.
        bedrooms = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bedrooms', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        bathrooms = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bathrooms', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        usual_cleaning_requirements = models.CharField(db_column='Usual_Cleaning_Requirements', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        feature_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='properties',null=True)

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'Property'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.property_reference

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("properties:property_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


    class Bedroom(models.Model):
        type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', choices=BEDROOM_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=50)
        bed_dimensions = models.CharField(db_column='Bed_Dimension', choices=BED_DIMENSION_CHOICES, max_length=30)
        image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
        ensuite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bedroom')
```

I have a Property DetailView Class that shows all the details on my template at "property-detail.html". Also on my template I have a button like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary float-right" href="{% url 'properties:add_bedroom' pk=object.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add New</a>
```

This button takes me to the right place, to the form AddBedroom with this link:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/properties/1/bedrooms/add-bedroom/

My urls.py look like this:

```
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.PropertyDetailView.as_view(),name='property_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$',views.PropertyUpdateView.as_view(),name='property_edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/bedrooms/add-bedroom/',views.add_bedroom,name='add_bedroom'),
```

You can see here how I render the form:

```
#views.py
def add_bedroom(request, pk):
    print(pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddBedroomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            add_bedroom = form.save()
            add_bedroom.instance.property = Property.objects.get(pk = pk)
            print('Sucesso')
            add_bedroom.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        print('Error')
        form = AddBedroomForm()

    context = {
        'add_bedroom_form':form,
        'title':"Add Bedroom",
    }
    return render(request, 'properties/add-bedroom.html', context)
```

I can get the "PK" printed, I also get the POST on console but it just refreshes the page and does not actually POSTS anything. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong because I'm fairly new to Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came up with a solution, I don't know if it's the best practice but it's working fine.

I've changed the views.py to this:

```
#views.py
def add_bedroom(request, pk):
    get_property_id = pk
    data = {'property':get_property_id}
    property_reference = Property.objects.get(pk=get_property_id)
    print(property_reference)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddBedroomForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial=data)
        print(get_property_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            add_bedroom = form.save()
            add_bedroom.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        print('Error')
        form = AddBedroomForm(initial=data)

    context = {
        'add_bedroom_form':form,
        'title':"Add Bedroom",
        'reference':property_reference,
    }
    return render(request, 'properties/add-bedroom.html', context)
```